# Java: Creating File or Directory if not existent

Tags: java, file, exception, io, nullpointerexception

My class gets a String containing a Path (dir1/dir2/abc.txt) or a file (def.txt) and I want to write/read into that file. If the file does not exist I want to create the directories (if there are any) and the file.

My class constructor so far("pfad" is a instance-variable):

```
public SerializedFahrzeugDAO(String path) {
    pfad=path;

    try{


        FileInputStream filein= new FileInputStream(pfad);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(filein);
        List<Fahrzeug> liste = (List<Fahrzeug>)in.readObject();
        in.close();
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(pfad);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileout);

        out.writeObject(liste);
        out.close();

    }
    catch (Exception f){
        if(f instanceof FileNotFoundException){
            try{
                File ziel = new File(pfad);
                File dir= new File(ziel.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
                dir.mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(pfad);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileout);
                List<Fahrzeug> newlist = new ArrayList<Fahrzeug>();
                out.writeObject(newlist);
                out.close();
            }
            catch(Exception y){System.out.println(y); }
        }

        else {System.out.println(f);}}
```

It works fine with paths like "dir/file.txt", but if I only enter a filename I get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Look closer at the stacktrace. Where is the exception thrown? Post the whole stacktrace so we can maybe help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a stacktrace, I would assume, the exception happens here:

```
            File dir= new File(ziel.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

`ziel` doesn't have a parent, so `ziel.getParentFile()` is `null`.

You could first convert to absolute path then get the parent.

---

Edit (1):

You should improve your error handling.

```
        catch(Exception y){System.out.println(y); }
```

Doesn't print the stacktrace. You should use `y.printStackTrace()` instead (or a proper logging framework).

---

Edit (2):

Instead of catching a `FileNotFoundException`, you should check if the file exists using a method of `java.io.File`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, will check that rightaway.
Sorry for the missing Stacktrace, I had to start learning Java for a University-Project about a week ago, so I basically have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Thank you, you were right.  Stuff like that happens when you just use code from stackoverflow without thinking..